# Import CSV Files from remote server in postgresql using pgadmin3

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin

I need the syntax for specifying FILE PATH " to upload CSV files located in  the remote server  protected by username and password.

I am able to upload the files with the following syntax if the csv files are placed locally .

```
COPY my_table FROM 'c:\localsystem\file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

Comment: `copy` command can access only to the local filesystem

Comment: Use the psql client and then the \copy command. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html